# Angular : Output a callback of my Custom directive event and subscribe to it in my component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Under my Angular app , i ve done a Custom directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appCustomEdit]'
})

export class CustomEditDirective implements OnChanges {

  @Input() appCustomEdit: boolean;
  private element: any;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.element = el.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.appCustomEdit.currentValue) {
      const btnElement = (<HTMLElement>this.element)
        .querySelector('.dx-link-save');

      this.renderer.listen(btnElement, 'click', () => {
        alert('Buton was clicked')
      });
    }
  }
}
```

in **myComponent.html** i m using this directive :

```
<div>
  <input [appCustomEdit]=true></input> 
</div>
```

i need now to implement some event / observable outputed from the directive so that i can subscribe to it in **myComponent.ts** and make some actions.

**I wonder how to do it ?**

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: Not really sure anyone would understand your code. What are you trying to get from this: `const btnElement = (<HTMLElement>this.element).querySelector('.dx-link-save');`? ElementRef that's injected in constructor _**is**_ your button (i.e. `<input>`) element. What else are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, direct answer to your question would be something like the following:

```
import {Directive, EventEmitter, HostListener, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appCustomInput]'
})
export class CustomInputDirective {

    @Output()
    myCustomEvent = new EventEmitter();

    @HostListener('click')
    onClick() {
        this.myCustomEvent.emit();
    }

}
```

And then use it like this:

```
<div>
  <input appCustomInput (myCustomEvent)="onMyCustomEvent()"></input> 
</div>
```

However, it is not clear what are you trying to achieve with this, so I cannot really say if this is the way to go or not.